# Storing UUIDs in Core Data

Tags: ios, core-data, uuid

What is the best method for storing UUIDs (for global multi-system object identification) in Core Data? Taking into account storage size and indexing capabilities.

Ideally it would be stored as binary data (in 128-bits), but are there any immediate problems with doing this? It would be more efficient size-wise storing it this way rather than as an NSString, but I just want to check that there's no performance issues with storing this as binary data. Will it still be properly indexed as binary data? Are there any disadvantages storing what is effectively fixed-width binary data in a variable width field?

I'm not overly familiar with SQLite and it's storage/indexing mechanisms so wanted to reach out for some advice!

Comment: What exactly is the problem with using the built in GUID type? Obviously you don't want to store a UUID as a string, but there is a specific DB type for this.

Comment: There's no GUID attribute type in Core Data. If by GUID you mean the managed object ID's created by Core Data, this isn't an option because the IDs need to be persistent and unique across several disparate systems.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How many of these are you planning on storing? Storing them as binary data saves about 50% -- roughly 20 bytes as binary data vs. roughly 40 bytes as a string. So you're talking about saving a whole 20K per thousand UUID's, which isn't so much that I'd worry about it either way. However, if you really want to save them as binary data, you can do that by storing them as NSData objects.

Comment: Do you know if the "binary data" fields are properly indexable?

Comment: Did you set the "Indexed" flag for that attribute in your model?

Comment: Yes that's ticked. I'm just wondering about any internal problems or things I should know about with storing and indexing small blobs.

Comment: I usually save them as NSStrings.  This makes viewing and writing queries pretty straightforward.  I never had any problems disk size.

Answer (score 24):

Starting at iOS 11, you can set UUID attribute directly in Core Data editor. UUID will be stored as binary automatically.

[image]

You can then fetch your Core Data objects using `UUID` (in Obj-C, `NSUUID`).

```
static func fetch(with identifier: UUID) -> AudioRecord? {
    var record: AudioRecord?
    moc.performAndWait {
        let fetchRequest = AudioRecord.request
        fetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "identifier == %@", identifier as CVarArg)
        fetchRequest.fetchLimit = 1
        record = (try? fetchRequest.execute())?.first
    }
    return record
}
```

Comment: Do I have to set the `identifier` value, or is it created for me automatically?

Comment: I agree, it seems to start out life as nil. That seems silly, since it’s obvious what it should mean to have a uuid, but I already had code for setting the uuid, so it’s no extra work. Thanks!

Comment: @matt you can set `primitiveIdentifier = UUID()` in `NSManagedObject.awakeFromInsert()` so your Core Data objects will always have default identifiers (non-nil).

Comment: @matt you need to declare `@NSManaged var identifier: UUID` and `@NSManaged private var primitiveIdentifier: UUID`

Answer (score 0):

I store my UUID as "Transformable" and it works well.

1. Add this to your `NSManagedObject` subclass:
   `@NSManaged var uuid: NSUUID!`
2. in your core data model (.xcdatamodel file), create an attribute with name `uuid` with Type `Transformable`

Querying works well too, I write my predicates to search on them like this:

`request.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "uuid == %@", withUuid)`